# Which (third-party) debug visualizers for Visual Studio 2005/2008 do you use?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debuggervisualizer

I guess this topic is often overseen, but is rather useful when debugging your code. Just today I have stumbled across this simple yet effective visualizer that visualizes images (it's on a german blog, but I guess the code content is self-explanatory):

[link text](http://blogs.msdn.com/dparys/archive/2007/10/23/das-debugger-visualizer-item-template.aspx)

I would like to know which debug visualizers you use in your daily work with VS2005/2008.

Answer (score 8):

I use [Mole](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-for-visual-studio/).

> Mole was designed to not only allow
>   the developer to view objects or data,
>   but to also allow the developer to
>   drill into properties of those objects
>   and then edit them. Mole allows
>   unlimited drilling into objects and
>   sub-objects.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out Xml Visualizer v.2 (http://codeplex.com/XmlVisualizer)

Answer (score 0):

There was a sample on an MSDN blog for the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Matrix, I think it was. I later made my own, but it was still good.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do a lot with Graphics and GDI, I found the [Graphic Debug Visualizer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/GraphicDebuggerVisualizer.aspx) invaluable.  The [Bitmap Visualizer](http://blogs.geekdojo.net/brian/archive/2006/08/06/bitmapvisualizer.aspx) it is based on is good too, however I had to recompile it for Visual Studio 2008 (and change the references to the various VisualStudio extension dll's).