# Which debug visualizers exists out there?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, debuggervisualizer

I know about this question: [Which (third-party) debug visualizers for Visual Studio 2005/2008 do you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100548/which-third-party-debug-visualizers-for-visual-studio-20052008-do-you-use)

But I don't want to know what debug visualizers you use, I want to know which debug visualizers are *out* there.

I have only found Mole (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/MoleForVisualStudioEdit.aspx), which is great. But there has to be plenty more out there?

Enlighten me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a quick web search...

There is the one referenced in the blog post from the related question:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/dparys/archive/2007/10/23/das-debugger-visualizer-item-template.aspx
- [LINQ to SQL Debug Visualizer](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer)
- [Graphics Debug Visualizer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24211/Graphics-Debugger-Visualizer)
- [Windows Identity Debug Visualizer](https://web.archive.org/web/20200725224405/http://geekswithblogs.net/khanna/archive/2006/01/05/64903.aspx)
- [Conchango XML Debug Visualizer](https://web.archive.org/web/20090813175627/http://blogs.conchango.com:80/howardvanrooijen/archive/2005/11/24/2424.aspx)
- [SubSonic Collections Debug Visualizer](https://track.vcdc.com/proceed.php?domain=subsonicproject.com&hash=fff186fca48a5e41a363c0d2382a6966&u=eyJkb21haW4iOiJzdWJzb25pY3Byb2plY3QuY29tIiwiZG9tYWluX2lkIjoiNTY1MDg5OSIsImZvbGRlcl9pZCI6bnVsbCwibWlkIjoiMTUxIiwiZmlsdGVyX2lkIjpudWxsLCJhZHZlcnRpc2VyX2lkIjoiMTI4IiwidGFyZ2V0IjoiaHR0cDpcL1wveG1sLXY0LnB4ZmluZG9uZS5jb21cL2NsaWNrP2k9MFBHTmdQeXNqRDhfMCIsImlwX2FkZHJlc3MiOiIxNDMuMTc3LjE4Ni4xMTQiLCJ0eXBlIjoiamF2YV9yZWRpcmVjdCIsImJpZCI6IjAuMDIxNyJ9)
- [PowerShell Debug Visualizer](https://web.archive.org/web/20100130144420/http://www.codeplex.com:80/PoSHDebugVisualizer)
- [Xml Visualizer v.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20100213062526/http://www.codeplex.com:80/XmlVisualizer)
- [WCF Visualizers Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20100125224103/http://www.codeplex.com:80/WCFVisualizer)
- [WPF Dependency Object Visualizer](https://web.archive.org/web/20100131044056/http://www.codeplex.com:80/dathanliblikdepo)
- [DB Connection Visualizer](https://web.archive.org/web/20100324013610/http://www.codeplex.com:80/dbvisualizer)
- [Debugger Visualizer for BizTalk 2006: MessageContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/gzunino/)
- [DataSet Debug Visualizer](https://web.archive.org/web/20140430153156/http://cs.rthand.com:80/blogs/blog_with_righthand/pages/Righthand-Dataset-Debugger-Visualizer.aspx)
- [GUID Debug Visualizer](https://devmatter.blogspot.com/2006/04/guid-debugger-visualizer-for-visual.html)
- [Debug Inspector](https://web.archive.org/web/20090122050040/http://visualstudiogallery.com:80/ExtensionDetails.aspx?ExtensionID=f52d4c99-a49f-4d5e-9251-97669a15038d)
- [WPF Brush Visualizer](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222180002/http://brushvisualizer.codeplex.com/)
- [Expression Tree Visualizer](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer)
- [ANTLR4 Parse Tree Visualizer](https://github.com/zspitz/ANTLR4ParseTreeVisualizer)
- [DateTime Visualizer](https://github.com/zspitz/DateTimeVisualizer)

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Regex Kit](http://osherove.com/blog/2005/11/26/announcing-regex-kit-regular-expression-visualizers-for-vs-2.html), a regular expression debugger visualizer.